# Consume Web API haing Action methods with custom name

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, httpclient

I am trying to consume web api in which action method names are custome like CreateCustomer(..), GetCustomer(...). These are annotated with [HttpPost]/[HttpGet]. I am not sure how to consume it using HttpClient(). If is set as following and me a call

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://host/directory/");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
var response = client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/customer", cutomerObj).Result;
```

It throws 404. Where as if i use fiddler and send arequest to http://host/directory/api/customer with JSON customer object it works perfectly

What exactly am i missing here? Do i need to user POST and GET as methods?

Comment: you need to configure your route to include the `action` like `api/{controller}/{action}/{id}` and make call like `api/customer/CreateCustomer`.

Comment: Was this post helpful?

Comment: i have already cionfigured my route as such

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to configure your route to include the `action` like `api/{controller}/{action}/{id}` and make call like `api/customer/CreateCustomer`

[image]

[image]

from C#,

```
var t = new HttpClient().GetAsync("http://localhost:63154/api/UserApi/CreateCustomer").Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

Comment: Thanks. it worked. Since i was posting a custom class to the method. I had to make following changes
var response = client.PostAsJsonAsync("http://host/directory/api/customer/createcustomer", customerObj).Result;

Comment: exactly, as `HttpContent`.