# web api 2 returning error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have created a new web api action and have added new routing for it.  I am not sure if I have done this right, most probably have not which is why I am getting this error.

So I have added my method/Action like this

```
    public IQueryable<Devices> GetLatestDevice(DateTime? latestUpdate)
    {
        return db.devices.Where(dev => dev.UpdatedDate > latestUpdate); ;
    }
```

and this is my routing table

```
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        //routes.IgnoreRoute("");
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Device",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{lastUpdate}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", lastUpdate = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

and this is how I attempt to get data:

```
http://localhost:53658/api/DevicesAPI/21-01-2001

    <Error><Message>An error has occurred.</Message><ExceptionMessage>Multiple actions were found that match the request: 
GetLatestDevice on type WhitespiderMonitor.Controllers.DevicesAPIController
GetDevices on type WhitespiderMonitor.Controllers.DevicesAPIController</ExceptionMessage><ExceptionType>System.InvalidOperationException</ExceptionType><StackTrace>   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionSelector.ActionSelectorCacheItem.SelectAction(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionSelector.SelectAction(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
   at System.Web.Http.ApiController.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()</StackTrace></Error>
```

My guesses are because the routes are pretty much the same it can't distinguish the two, so my questions really are am I correct in that they are the same, and how would I get it so that it would pick up the date. More information can be provided if needed, thanks!

I have no updated the routes table to

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Device",
            url: "DevicesAPI/GetLatestDevice/{lastUpdate}",
            defaults: new { lastUpdate = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

and now get this error:

```
<Error><Message>The request is invalid.</Message><MessageDetail>The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int64' for method 'System.Web.Http.IHttpActionResult GetDevices(Int64)' in 'WhitespiderMonitor.Controllers.DevicesAPIController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.</MessageDetail></Error>
```

Comment: Your both route are generic and matching with same request.Just hardcode the controller and action name. e..g replace this  url: "{controller}/{action}/{lastUpdate}", with  url: "Device/GetLatestDevice/{lastUpdate}"

Comment: So i should delete the route that I just created and just use the hardcoded url?

Comment: no replace the first route URL value with this. There should be one route with dynamic controller & action name so that other functionality should not affect.

Comment: @AnupamSharma so I have tried this http://localhost:53658/api/DevicesAPI/GetLatestDevices/21-01-2001 and got a 404 error, andhave also tried your suggestion http://localhost:53658/DevicesAPI/GetLatestDevices/21-01-2001 and got another error saying resource cannot be found.  I have also tried doing it this way http://localhost:53658/api//DevicesAPI/GetLatestDevices?latestUpdate=21-01-2001 but said the same as above that there were multiple actions that were the same

Comment: Keep both route there one with hardcoded value and other with dynamic value as it is now. Or you can do one more think make parameter name same and keep only one generic root.

Comment: what is your controller name??

Comment: Controller name is DevicesAPI

Comment: Replace your first route with this routes.MapRoute(
            name: "DevicesAPIRoute",
            url: "DevicesAPI/GetLatestDevice/{latestUpdate}",
            defaults: new { controller = "DevicesAPI", action = "GetLatestDevice", lastUpdate = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

Comment: I have done this but got the error above when I try to use the URL http://localhost:53658/api/DevicesAPI/21-01-2001  I have amended the post above

Comment: pz try the answer i have posted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83106/discussion-between-anupam-sharma-and-johnathon64).

Comment: read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31287928/consume-web-api-haing-action-methods-with-custom-name/31288134#31288134

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please replace the action method with the below code.

```
   public IQueryable<Devices> GetLatestDevice(DateTime latestUpdate)
    {
        return db.devices.Where(dev => dev.UpdatedDate > latestUpdate); 
    }
```

And Add the below routing code in WebAPIConfig.cs before the default existing routing code.

```
     Routes.MapHttpRoute(
         name: "CustomApi",
         routeTemplate:"api/{controller}/{action}/{latestUpdate:DateTime?}",
         defaults: new { controller:"DevicesAPI",latestUpdate = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two generic routes. You can change one into something like:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    //routes.IgnoreRoute("");
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Device",
        url: "device/{action}/{lastUpdate}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Device", action = "Index", lastUpdate = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

So specific one will be hit when using `Device` controller.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to add the `action` parameter in your routing code like :

```
Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```

You'll need to pass the `action` name in your url like following:

```
http://localhost:53658/api/DevicesAPI/{your action name}/21-01-2001
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: @Johnathon64 - can you give this a try?

Answer (score 0):

Your route should be like this:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        //routes.IgnoreRoute("");
        routes.MapRoute( name: "DevicesAPIRoute", 
                          url:"DevicesAPI/GetLatestDevice/{latestUpdate}", 
                          defaults: new { controller = "DevicesAPI", action = "GetLatestDevice", lastUpdate = UrlParameter.Optional } ); 

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Comment: URL that you are trying?

Comment: Just for a workaround can you comment-out the first route(means hardcoded one). keep only one route there and change your action parameter name as id. and Try this if its working for you.

Comment: I got a 404 resource not found, I tried the other actions and they work.

Comment: remove the api from URL or add that in route also

Comment: Tried this and also did not work.  It does not seem to want to pick up the new method I added in

Comment: So apparently if I write my route like this it seems to work http://localhost:53658/api//DevicesAPI?lastUpdate=21-02-2012